# Traefik/SSL/LetsEncrypt Faulty

Tags: docker, ssl, networking, proxy, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up letsEncrypt with traeffik and whatever I do it appears not to work. At the moment I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Other SO posts have mentioned that this may be due to not using the http challenge for traeffik ([Traefik will issue certificate instead of Let's encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408184/traefik-will-issue-certificate-instead-of-lets-encrypt?rq=1)), but I'm using that so I have no idea honestly (this doesn't solve the issue - do not close). My configuration files appear to be small, but I'm getting no error feedback so my ability to iterate on breaks is small. If anyone can provide any help on how to fix this I would appreciate it - I've been at this for a while and I'm at a loss for what to do.

I spin up the following three files below using this small bash script:

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01:/lowteck# cat ./runSwarm.sh 
#!/bin/bash

./buildandpush.sh
cd ./back
./buildandpush.sh
cd ..

docker volume prune -f
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
 docker swarm init \
   --advertise-addr 104.236.214.151
docker network create -d overlay --attachable proxy
docker stack deploy --compose-file=stage.yaml prod2 
docker stack deploy --compose-file=traefik.yaml prodTraefik
```

Here is my `traefik.toml`:

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01:/lowteck# cat traefik.toml 
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.forwardedHeaders]
    trustedIPs = ["104.236.214.151"]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
  caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
  email = "pweyand@gmail.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  onHostRule = true 
  [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "lowteck.com"
  sans = ["www.lowteck.com"]

[docker]
  domain = "traefik"
  watch = true
  swarmmode = true
  network="web"
```

Here is my `traefik.yaml`:

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01:/lowteck# cat traefik.yaml 
version: '3.3'

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

configs:
  traefik.toml:
    file: ./traefik.toml

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    configs:
      - source: traefik.toml
        target: /etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    networks:
      - proxy
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

Here is my `stage.yaml`:

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01:/lowteck# cat stage.yaml 
version: "3.3"

networks:
  default:
    external: false
  proxy:
    external: true

services:
  back:
    image: patientplatypus/lowtechback:latest
    ports: 
      - '5000:5000'
    networks:
      - proxy
      - default
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 120s
      labels:
        - "traefik.docker.backend=back"
        - "traefik.port=5000"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:back.lowteck.com"
        - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
  front:
    image: patientplatypus/lowtechfront:latest
    ports: 
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - proxy
      - default
    depends_on:
      - back
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 120s
      labels:
        - "traefik.docker.backend=front"
        - "traefik.port=3000"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:104.236.214.151, lowteck.com, www.lowteck.com, zennify.me"
        - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

Again, I've been at this for a while, and I have essentially no error codes on which to go on. If anyone has any advice please let me know.

EDIT:

I found an error after logging out the traefik pod - namely that I needed:

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "lowteck.com"
  sans = ["www.lowteck.com", "back.lowteck.com"]
```

However this has not solved the https problem although the logs are now clear for the traefik container. You can see the full log output here: https://gist.github.com/patientplatypus/8a40e12c6ba64cdc7d2bf88581967057.

Comment: Can you post the log of the traefik container when it starts? It should show its activity regarding ACME/Let's Encrypt

Comment: @Thomasleveil - thanks for the suggestion - that helped debug at least one potential error, although I am getting the same error when attempting to get to https. You can see the full logs above in my EDIT.

Comment: give a try to `"traefik.frontend.rule=Host:lowteck.com,www.lowteck.com,zennify.me,104.236.214.151"`. If that works, I'll give details on why that was causing the issue

Comment: Now, I'm getting that the certificate generates from the logs - I'm assuming because the certs are somehow hashed as unique to the order of the domains used regardless of the domains themselves (dumb) - but I'm still getting that https is self signed by traefik and not letsEncrypt when navigating in the browser. Logs because why not (https://gist.github.com/patientplatypus/c02ddc366f8493800bc799453fb7492e)

Comment: add `acmeLogging = true` under the `[acme]` section in your toml file, it might give new hints

Comment: also, `back.lowteck.com` is resolvable by public DNS, that might bother Let's Encrypt

Comment: hmmm...I'm getting a lot of this `prodTraefik_traefik.1.su95hc25ozfw@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01    | time="2019-03-16T22:26:00Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container without port, prodTraefik_traefik.1: port label is missing, please use traefik.port as default value or define port label for all segments ('traefik.<segment_name>.port')"` - which doesn't make sense. My `traefik.yaml` file should be the load balancer and be "above" the level of `traefik.port`. I tried adding it but it gave really bizarro errors from that.

Comment: Removing `back.lowteck.com` now gives no errors but also doesn't resolve the issue. Not sure adding or leaving it matters although the docs suggest to leave it (https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#domains) ...so I guess I'll leave it. idk?

Comment: So [this](https://gist.github.com/AndrewSav/04cd73172bf7fafd9113f730bad6c6fa), based on your post, works with valid certs and all, I just tested it. Try it and if it works (it should) try to find differences between your setup and that.

Comment: I'm not  sure I understand your example Andrew - specifically `traefik.port=80` is in there for both the front and back. Doesn't that mean you are assigning the same port to multiple containers - that should mean that one of those containers is now inaccessible. Other than that you've commented out the `caServer`, but I'm not sure that should matter either way - I think it's default.

Comment: Sorry, not sure where confusion comes from, it is correct that the port is the same, but as far as inaccessibility goes, it's not clear why you concluded that. I'm repeating myself, but that setup that I showed works - I tested it. Change the domain names to your own and try it. And then go from there, to make your own example work. You are close. `caServer` is commented out because I tested at LE staging before testing it at LE production.

Comment: Oh and don't forget to make sure that all the DNS that you are expecting LE to generated certs for resolve to the ip where your containers are.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it resolved and there are a few things that helped that I want to point out for anyone who comes across this.

1) You should log your traefik pod using `docker service logs YOURTRAEFFICPOD` to get any and all errors to debug. For some reason this hadn't occurred to me (dumb).

2) The acme sans portion isn't defined by pod but by what is in your A records for the domain. If it's not in the A records don't put it there - this will show up in the logs as an error.

3) Make sure that you are using the latest version of traefik - In my case I had to change the traefik version to 1.7.9 by changing `traefik.toml` to have the line `image: traefik:v1.7.9`

4) If you are using the http challenge your acme.json file will and should be empty - so don't worry about this.

5) Finally, if you are getting the error that you have gone over your maximum amount of certificate requests for your domain from letsEncrypt, this may not in fact force your domain not to have https - you should check as it may still be able to use a previous cert.

That's it and thanks to everyone for all the help!